# mercurial log of changests on merged named branches, but not unmerged

Tags: mercurial, branch, logging

I want to be able to get a "hg log" of every changeset that appears in the graph between 
changeset1 and changeset2.  I cannot find a way to do it without either 
a) omitting nodes on named branches that ARE merged between changeset1:changset2
or b) including nodes on named branches that ARE NOT ancestors of changeset2

Here's a "hg glog" of a simple example with 2 named branches plus the default branch. One named branch gets merged and so its nodes are relevant, the other is irrelevant:

```
@    changeset:   5:e384fe418e9b
|\   tag:         tip
| |  parent:      2:7dc7af503071
| |  parent:      3:0a9be59d576e
| |  summary:     merge somefeature branch into default
| |
| | o  changeset:   4:4e8c9ca127c9
| | |  branch:      unmerged_feature
| | |  parent:      1:ef98ad136fa8
| | |  summary:     change that is not merged into ending changeset
| | |
| o |  changeset:   3:0a9be59d576e
| |/   branch:      somefeature
| |    parent:      1:ef98ad136fa8
| |    summary:     changed b.txt
| |
o |  changeset:   2:7dc7af503071
|    summary:     changed a.txt
|
o  changeset:   1:ef98ad136fa8
|  summary:     added b.txt
|
o  changeset:   0:271b22b4ad30
   summary:     added a.txt
```

I want a log command that will give me all the nodes that are descendent of rev 0 and ancestors of rev 5.  This is everything except rev 4.

I can get too much info:

```
hg log -r 0:5 --template "{rev}:branch={branches},desc={desc}\n"
```

This gives me a log entry for rev 4, which is not an ancestor of rev 5:

```
0:branch=,desc=added a.txt
1:branch=,desc=added b.txt
2:branch=,desc=changed a.txt
3:branch=somefeature,desc=changed b.txt
4:branch=unmerged_feature,desc=change that is not merged into ending changeset
5:branch=,desc=merge somefeature branch into default
```

I can get too little info:

```
hg log -b default -r 0:5 --template "{rev}:branch={branches},desc={desc}\n"
```

omits rev 3, which is a descendent of rev 0 and ancestor of rev 5

```
0:branch=,desc=added a.txt
1:branch=,desc=added b.txt
2:branch=,desc=changed a.txt
5:branch=,desc=merge somefeature branch into default
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a newer version of Mercurial (1.6.0 or higher), you can use the [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets) feature.  In this case, you need the ancestors() operator:

```
hg log --rev ancestors(5)
```

See `hg help revsets` for more information.

Comment: Thanks.  I had not seen that before.  What I really want is :    hg log --rev 'ancestors(changeset2) and descendants(changeset1)'

Comment: Actually, it looks like the double colon will do what I want more simply: hg log --rev 'changeset1::changeset2'

Comment: Yes, you want the `X::Y` syntax -- I put it in for this purpose :-)

Comment: Now I wonder how hgweb's pretty graphs could be coerced into producing such fine output!  `hg glog --rev foo::bar` shows you a nice graphic depicting how two revisions are related, but hgweb doesn't show you that...