# Mercurial log that includes the ancestry of a final revision but excludes anything on the default branch prior to the starting revision

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-revsets

I am working on a script that parses a mercurial log and generates a report of all changes between any two revisions.  In order to handle branches, I believe I need to use [revsets](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets) to generate ancestry of the final revision but I want to limit the scope to exclude any revisions which are ancestors to the starting revision.

```
   10
  /
 / 
9
|\
| \
|  \
8   | 
|   7
| 6 |
|/  |   
5   4
|  / 
| /
|/
3 
|   
| 
|
2
|
|
|
1
```

At 3, a feature branch is created from the default branch.

At 5, a release branch (6) is created from the default branch.

At 9, the feature branch is merged back to default and a new release (10) is created.

I want a list of all changes since 5 that affect 10 => 4,5,7,8,9,10

The difficulty I am having is limiting the ancestry search when 3 is reached via the feature branch.  I don't want it since 3 was already a part of 5.

Other discussions I reviewed:

[Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494399/mercurial-log-of-changests-on-merged-named-branches-but-not-unmerged) but didn't help with limiting the scope.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991969/mercurial-see-changes-on-the-branch-ignoring-all-the-merge-commits) implies you know the branch but I need to find them all dynamically.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your requirements. You want changes since 5, but also include 4 in this set? Is "since" meant to imply a chronological order or ancestry in the revision graph (note that 4 would be included in neither) or something else?

Comment: Why is 6 omitted from the list of changes you want to see? And is there a reason why you don't just say all changes since 3 but excluding 3?

Comment: The reason I want to include 4 and 7 is because they are merged into the default branch at 9 and therefore they will be included as part of 10.  6 is not to be included because it was not merged back into the default branch and therefore is not included in 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if your **business-task** is *"What's new in release"*, best iteration of revset will be `ancestors(LAST) - ancestors(PREVIOUS)`, i.e. for your sample

```
hg log -r "ancestors(10) - ancestors(6)"
```

(note missing r5 in output, because **it was** in 6)

maybe revset will be more usable in [revsetalias] with alias added for better readability, smth.like (untested!!!)

```
[revsetalias]
new($1,$2) = ancestors($1) - ancestors($2)

[alias]
cl = log -r "new($1,$2)" --style changelog
```

Comment: Also note that I looking for the ancestors between 5 and 10 do the suggested command would be **hg log -r "ancestors(10) - ancestors(5)"**, which I modified to be **hg log -r "ancestors(10) - ancestors(p1(5))"** since the output was not inclusive of 5.

Comment: @sje - In cleanly writen **my** bisiness-task (which *have* internal logic)  5 is a wrong bounary, and for `ancestors(p1(5)` I'm totally out of idea "that is it" in RL-terms